# Event based gateway in jBPM 5 or 5.1?

Tags: jbpm, bpmn

i am currently trying to model event based gateways. Currently i'am not finding an icon for event based gatway in the BPMN 2.0 notation supported by jBPM 5.0.
Is there any solution for realizing this in the current version of jBPM 5 or jBPM 5.1.

THX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event-based gateway is currently not yet supported in the graphical editor, but the engine does support it.  You can take a look at some examples here:
https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/tree/master/jbpm-bpmn2/src/test/resources
(BPMN2-EventBasedSplit*.bpmn2)

Kris